# Questions about texture atlas and render sorting - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures

I am emulating an old client and most of the textures are 128x128. As I know switching textures and render calls are expensive, could I get away with at runtime, creating a very large texture atlas of all the tiny textures.

Then from there, could I bind the large texture and render via shaders with the texture offset in the atlas? What kind of performance hit would this have?
My second question is involving sorting. The level files are broken up into little chunks of a BSP tree. They are very small and there are often thousands per level. The current way, which is definitely slower is that I render each group of textures in each BSP leaf that are in my frustum and PVS (Quake 3 style). What would be the idea fix for this?

Would I want to run through each region (back to front) I could see, and group all of the visible triangles by texture and then render all at once. For some reason, I always feel this may be slower. Does it make more sense to sort first and render all at once or skip sorting and render each region at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible to stuff textures into a texture atlas. Careful consideration would need to be given to issues like whether the textures are being tiled, and what you want to happen with mip-maps and filtering.

I'd probably suggest holding off on doing that until you've got the geometry sorted out - reducing the number of draw calls to a sane number may well be all you need to do. The cost of changing a texture isn't necessarily *that* bad on modern hardware.

As for rendering the level, on modern hardware it's more usual to render front to back, rather than back to front, in order to take advantage of the z-buffer and early culling (i.e. if you have a wall right in front of the camera, and you draw that first with z-buffering enabled, the hardware is fairly good at rejecting stuff you then try to draw behind it).

One possible approach would be to reprocess the BSP into a rougher structure, such as a simple grid (or maybe a quad or oct tree). You don't even need to split polygons neatly, just have a bunch of sectors with a bounding-box around them, and frustum-cull then loosely sort (front to back) the boxes. You can keep a PVS with this approach too, but the usefulness of that might drop when your rendering chunks become larger and coarser.

However before doing any of this, I'd definitely recommend setting up some benchmark tests and recording performance information. You won't know for sure if you're doing the right thing unless you actually analyse the performance. If you can pinpoint exactly what the worst performant thing you are doing is, you just need to fix that.